# How to change players?

Tags: the-cave

I'm playing "The Cave". In the start of the game I choose three players. Can I change them in the continuation of the game? And should I do it? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't choose which characters you're playing as in the middle of a playthrough; it's designed so you can only play three characters' stories at a time, so you can get through the game without needing to. The only way to play as other characters is to select them the next time you start a new game.

There are some areas that can only be accessed by certain characters that you may not have, but there's no way to get to every area in a single playthrough, so don't worry about those areas if you see them.

Comment: What's the meaning of "single playthrough"? I can't understand it.

Comment: By "playthrough" I mean one time through the game--going from start to finish with the same three characters. If you want to see everything in the game, you'll eventually have to play it a few times (do multiple playthroughs), but you can finish the game with the three characters you choose at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change them during a single playthrough.

Though you could optimize your flow if you have a look at the order otf the caverns to come, so you don't have to go through all caverns the third time you play.

[image]

So take the Knight or Hillbilly for the **third** playthrough, if you don't care to see the end sequence for them.